# position a text element relative to another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form that carries info from one HTML to another using local storage. Since this text changes based on what the user inputs on the first HTML, I have to find a way to add a text element that stays with the output. For example: if a user types "Luke" and submits, ideally the next page will say "Luke's" (the "'s" being the separate text element). Since the text might be longer e.g. Lukas or Lucius, the "'s" text element has to stay at the end of the previous one regardless of its length.

```
<h1 id="show">
<!-- this is where the output text shows -->
      </h1>
```

```
<h1 class="epic1">'s epic <!-- this is what i want to stick to the  end of the output element -->
</h1>
```

I should also add that this JS isn't working...

```
  <script>
      
      document.getElementById("show").textContent += "'s";
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `:after` pseudo element for this. Its defined content will be added to any element that has the class it refers to, and it will be automatically styled the same way as the element it's appended to:

```css
.epic1:after {
  content: "'s epic";
}
```

```html
<h1 class="epic1">Tom</h1>
```

Comment: In this example, is the css taking the ‘“‘s epic” text from the content attribute, or from the HTML text element itself that’s containing the “‘s epic” in the h1?

Comment: You can see it in the code: "Tom" is the content of the `h1` tag, "'s epic"  is the content of the `:after` pseudo element. So "'s epic" would be added to *any* HTML element that has the `.epic1` class.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best way, but I added a div with a new class around the show element and used the ::after in css to add content.

```css
.hey ::after {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  content: "'s";
}
```

```html
<div class="hey">
  <h1 id="show">
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no need for the wrapper `div` and no need to style the pseudo element - see the example in my answer...